# Split the react-native-google-places-autocomplete into different fields

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-places-api, mobile-development

I am working on a uni project and I've installed the react-native-google places autocomplete search.

What I am trying to implement is the following:
a. I wanted to have a suggestion to appear when the user enters a city or street name... however, I am not sure how to split the Autocomplete search into multiple fields.
b. Since I might not be able to implement option a. I will let the user input the data and I was hoping I could in the code pass that data to the autocomplete (like an object) and fetch the results - basically do a search based on what the user input and select the first item returned.

However, I don't see any attribute on the autocomplete form where I could use implement option b.

The goal is to get the data through the form, pass it to the search and get the same results as I would when clicking on the dropdown.

I would really appreciate any feedback or suggestion, meanwhile, I will continue trying somethings out and do some further search.

[image]

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  placeholder='Search'
  fetchDetails={true}
  GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
    rankby: "distance"
  }}
  onPress={(data, details = null) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data, details);
  }}
  query={{
    key: 'API_KEY',
    language: 'en',
    components: 'country:uk',
    types: ["supermarket","grocery_or_supermarket","food","store", "establishment"],
    nearbyPlacesAPI: 'GooglePlacesSearch',
    radius: 30000
  }}
  enablePoweredByContainer={false}
  styles={{
    container: {flex:0, position: 'absolute', width: '100%', zIndex: 1},
    listView: {backgroundColor:"white"}
}}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting your API keys on public sites to prevent unauthorized use of it and cause billing issues on your end. I would suggest that you delete it and generate a new one and secure it as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices